# Retaining UITextfield values when moving between subviews in iPad app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

I am converting an iphone app to ipad.

In the iphone app i used a nav controller to move up and down a hierarchy of tables and views of different math calculators. Using the nav controller allowed me to retain the data values in each textfield of each view as I pushed and popped views.

In my ipad version of the app I am still using tables and a nav controller to move between major UIViews but I am using

```
[self.MyView insertSubview:nextController.view atIndex:1];
```

to add subviews within the UIViews. The subviews contain different math calculators that the user can switch in and out. I cannot find a way to load subviews within a UIView using a nav controller hence the use of insertSubView. While this method cleanly loads and unloads the different subviews I lose the feature of retaining the data values in the textfields as I load and unload subviews.

Could someone a method to either use nav controllers to load subviews within a UIView or suggest a way to retain data values between the loading and unloading of subviews. I would happy to provide code but I thought a gentle push in the right direction might be all I needed. I did not want to have to use plist or other data persistence approaches to solve this issue if I did not have to

Best regards,

Davew01

Answer (score 2):

Never use views to store data. Your data should always live in a separate model object, and the controller should only pass data to the view for the purposes of display. When you remove a view from the view hierarchy, your model object will still hold the data.